# VM Options not found at android studio setting

Tags: android

I use android studio 1.5.1 32 bit and getting error: "Gradle project sync failed.
I tried to make some searches on internet for this issue, I found something related to "VM Options" for compiler sitting. but this option I cannot locate it in my version.

So please i need to know how to get this issue solved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkZa9.png)

gratefully